# Elasticsearch Not Exist Value

Tags: sql, database, elasticsearch, elk

I was working on a query that I found. It's a little bit more complex than I thought. This is part of each data document which is distinguished by an event name.

```
"eventTime" : "2021-07-11T08:29:00-0800",
"userId" : "P9QuPERPURPC3swJpyBb4",
"eventName" : "mko", // mko and mkp are two possible values
"eventData" : {}
```

The target is: `userIds` who have `eventName('mko')` AND does not have `eventName('mkp')`

I could not precisely understand what is the best way to handle 'not exist' in `Elasticsearch` queries. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: can eventName have both `mko` and `mkp` values? (e.g., "eventName": [ "mko", "mkp"]) If not, like it seems from your question, isn't it enough to require that eventName is equal to "mko"?

Comment: Yes, a userId could generate many eventsNames with mko or mkp

Comment: please correct me if I'm wrong.
We have where not exist in SQL could minus two sets.

Comment: is this correct? (1) you can have documents with the same "userId" but different "eventName", (2) you want to know for which "userId"s you only have one given "eventName" (e.g, `mko`). E.g., doc1: `{ "userId": 1, "event": "mko" }`, doc2: `{ "userId": 1, "event": "mkp" }`, doc3: `{ "userId": 2, "event": "mko" }` -> the expected result is doc3 ?

Comment: Exactly :), each userId may have lots of documents with different eventNames.

Comment: In this case, I'm not aware of a single query solution, but you would need to (1) write one query to find the matches for the desired `eventName` and aggregate by `userId` to get the list of users, (2) write another query to find the matches for the undesired `eventName` and aggregate by `userId`, (3) remove from the list of `userId`s in 1 the ones found in 2. In the future, new EQL queries may give us a single query solution.

Comment: I totally agree. I found  (A - B) operation in the sets theory.  I think I must implement the concept in the application layer. really appreciate

Answer (score 1):

I think the below queries might help you.

Get a user with the name `mko`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "eventName": "mko"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Get a user with a name other than `mko`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "eventName": "mko"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Get a user with the name `mkp`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "eventName": "mkp"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Get a user with a name other than `mkp`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "eventName": "mkp"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

To get the selected fields only you can use the `_source` field in query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html.

And to check whether the field `eventName` is `exists` in a document. You can use the `exists` query within the `must` queries: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Actually, I'm looking for userIds who have eventName mkowhereas they do not have any document with eventName mkp

Comment: Also in each document, all fields exist.

Comment: In combination of these queries for example (bool (must[mko], must_not(mkp))) there is a logical error. There are userIds come from first query (must[mko]) AND again userIds come from must_not(mkp), because must_not does not mean not exist

Comment: You can use the following query to get eventName wmkowhereas userId only: ={"_source":{"includes":["userId"]},"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"eventName":"mkowhereas"}}]}}}

Comment: Just to be clear you mean to say that you want userId who have eventName as `mkowhereas` and not `mkp` Right?

Comment: Exactly, UserIds who have mko and does not have mkp

Comment: {"_source":{"includes":["userId"]},"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"eventName":"mkowhereas"}}]}}}
This does not return any document

Comment: To get only matching UserIds for `mko` name you don't need to pass `mkp` at all. Because query will return only UserIds who have eventName `mko`. And one more question. Do you have any pattern like `mko*` and possible values are `mkoanything`, `mkoxyz`.  If yes then in such a case you can use es match query. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

Comment: I totally agree with you, but how do I distinguish userIds who they have mko, they don't have any mkp document.

Comment: Also mko and mkp are two examples. the fact is I'm looking for userIds who has "start_text_message_click" document but they do not have "successful_payment" document

Comment: Yes, I understood that you want a document with `start_text_message_click`. So, You can use must query only. Because you don't need to check for the existing queries. Because must query will return exact match of your eventName and will not include any other name.